# Need help getting binomial (logit) output to R to a small sample

Tags: r, output, glm

I sat four hours yesterday attempting to get output from R, and I understand that I need to read up on R if using it in the future. I downloaded R for Mac using my university's guideline, but its guideline is out of date. When I tried downloading the latest version (+ extras) but kept getting errors.

However, I have a small set of data by which I need a generalized linear model - binomial(logit) output. Can anyone help me out obtaining it? I would be extremely grateful for such help. And I would also be grateful if I can get the "codes" too so I can learn from it. Thanks again.

```
sort   temp  survive total

  0     1       29    29 

  0     8       19    20 

  0    10       27    29 

  0    12       30    30 

  0    14       20    29 

  0    18       15    30 

  0    20       11    20 

  1     1       27    28

  1     8       21    28

  1    10       21    26

  1    12       20    27

  1    14        8    27

  1    18        4    30

  1    20        1    10
```

Comment: Once you successfully import it, you can use a `glm` function, along the lines of `glm(sort ~ temp * survive, data = your.data)`. But in truth, you provide insufficient information of how you plan on constructing your model. Additionally, this question is best addressed at crossvalidated.com.

Comment: Thank you for the code. I see that I have provided insufficient information. Survival is to be the response variable, and sort and temperature is predictor variable in a logistic regression model.

Comment: Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'temp' not found

Comment: Then you might want generalized linear mixed effects model... As before, ask on crossvalidated.com (with more information) or seek a professional statistician.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `survive` is the number of successes over `total` trials, `temp` and `sort` are your covariates, and your dataframe name is `db` then:

```
result <- glm(cbind(survive, total-survive) ~ temp+sort,family=binomial(logit), data=db)
```

then to see what you get

```
summary(result)
```

gives you (on your data)

```
Call:
glm(formula = cbind(survive, total - survive) ~ temp + sort, 
    family = binomial(logit), data = db)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-1.6671  -0.6430  -0.3071   0.9203   2.5942  

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)  5.90102    0.64433   9.158  < 2e-16 ***
temp        -0.31415    0.03823  -8.216  < 2e-16 ***
sort        -1.83193    0.31458  -5.823 5.77e-09 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 158.445  on 13  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance:  19.682  on 11  degrees of freedom
AIC: 62.063

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 5
```

Comment: Thanks! I have uploaded the dataset in R, but I get the error message Error in cbind(survive, total - survive) : object 'survive' not found

Comment: at a guess, you need `read.table("myfilename.dat",header=TRUE)` (the `header=TRUE` part is important)

Comment: Does not work. Can anyone post the resulting output here? I would appreciate it greatly. And then I will read more on R and try more data for myself. I keep getting the same error, so I ought to seek advice from my university. In the mean time, the output is greatly appreciated if anyone can spare the little time it takes. Cheers.

Comment: @Christopher There you are: edited answer

Comment: Thank you very much! I give you, if you don't mind, a virtual hug.

I will attempt to get similar results on R. Thanks again for the "codes"